# jQuery selector click not firing from dynamically generated button?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events

The following button is generated from an ajax success call (there are many of them):

```
<a class="btn appDetails" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" role="button">' + data.Application_Name + '</a>
```

I've tried all of the following and none of them seem to fire:

```
$('.appDetails').click(function () {
    alert("test");
});

$('.appDetails').live("click", function () {
    alert("test");
});

$('.appDetails').on("click", function () {
    alert("test");
});

$('document').on("click",".appDetails", function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

Probably missing something stupid... Note that clicking on the link *does* open the bootstrap modal properly.  Not sure if this conflicts, I wouldn't think so...

Comment: live is deprecated !!!!

Comment: OMG!!111!!!  :)  I know, I was just listing everything I tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do it this way

```
$(document).on("click",".appDetails", function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: EPIC FACEPALM

thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use $(document).ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.appDetails').live("click", function () {
        alert("test");
    });
});

// 1.7+
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".appDetails", function() { 
        alert("test"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that all the functions I listed are in the jquery ready event.

Comment: // 1.7 acutural works on me! thank you.